# "Read-only file system" error when Git tries to access index.lock

Tags: linux, git, unix, permissions

I haven't touched my local Git repository for a couple of days. Now when I cd to the root and type

```
git add -A :/
```

I get:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/james/code/winescan/Prototype/.git/index.lock': Read-only file system
```

Adding `sudo` to the command gives the same error. Then I tried `ls -al`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 james james   4096 Jul 28 16:24 .git
```

Then I tried changing the mode for the directory:

```
$ sudo chmod 0777 .git
[sudo] password for james: 
chmod: changing permissions of '.git': Read-only file system
```

Nothing seems to work, what do I do?

Comment: This is probably not a git issue, but linux FS issues try `sudo fsck -Af -M`

Comment: Make sure you have a recent backup, too …

Comment: What version of Git are you using?